# Changing doctype from XHTML to HTML5

Tags: asp.net, html, doctype

I have a .NET Master page with an XHTML DTD: `!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional ... >`.

My .NET .ascx input controls need to start using the HTML5 `placeholder` attribute. It's my understanding that browsers won't recognize `placeholder` unless the HTML5 DTD is used: `<!DOCTYPE html>`.

I'm leery about simply changing the Master page to use the HTML5 `doctype`. I've heard that the HTML5 spec is supposed to backwards support XHTML markup, but I'm wondering about any other adverse side-effects with this kind of blanket change. Does anyone have insight regarding this?

**Note:** Several web apps use the Master page so it would be a widespread change.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HTML5 is designed to be backwards compatible with XHTML and HTML so developers can easily migrate.

The only effect for you will be that the browser will not enforce the strict XHTML rules.
You can still follow the XHTML rules however but you aren't forced to.

So you can safely edit your doctype to the HTML5 doctype!

Comment: Thanks, Owain. I can live without XHTML rules being enforced. As long as HTML5 supports the same markup (self-closing tags) without any weird behavior.